# Express Set of Dyadic with union/complementation of closed intervals

Tags: general-topology

> Let $S = \{{m\over 2^n}|m\in\mathbb Z, n\in \mathbb N\cup\{0\}\}$
>
> 1. Can $S \cap[0,1]$ be expressed as countable union, complement or intersection of closed intervals with non zero, dyadic length and dyadic endpoints ?
> 2. Further, can any subset of $[0,1]$ be expressed with the same rules?

As for 1, as we can do the following:
Let $\{a_n\}_n$ be an enumeration of dyadics in $[0,1]$
def $A_n = [0,a_n]\cap[a_n,1] = \{a_n\}$
Then take a union of $A_n$'s
Incase $a_n = 0$ or $1$, we can create decreasing/increasing sequence of dyadics and then take complement
Is the solution correct? Please also provide hints/counterexample for 2

Comment: No and no for real intervals.

Comment: @WilliamElliot What is the problem with the solution?

Comment: The A's have zero length.

Comment: I have two questions to clarify yours. Dyadic numbers are exactly numbers belonging to $S$, right? Can we combine operations of countable union, complement or intersection several (maybe countably many) times? Even if so, the answer to Question 2 is negative, because all expessible sets belong to a $\sigma$-algebra of Borel subsets, and there are non-Borel subsets
(even [non-Lebesgue measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set)) contained in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky yes and yes, $S$ is exactly all dyadic numbers. Operations have to be countable (can be infinite)